# C++: Destructor being called outside object scope?

Tags: c++, destructor

**Update 1:** Added printing "this" as suggested.

**Update 2:** Split into several files to try and stop gcc from optimizing.

**Update 3:** Logged copy constructor and entering add functions.

**Update 4:** Added output from Clang and second cout in main.

I expect parameter destructors to be called as the last statements in a function. Henceforth, I would expect the following output from the code below.

```
default constructor: 008DFCF8
other constructor: 008DFCEC
copy constructor: 008DFBC0
in member add
destroying: 008DFBC0
copy constructor: 008DFBB8
copy constructor: 008DFBB4
in function add
destroying: 008DFBB4
destroying: 008DFBB8
3 == 3
end of main
destroying: 008DFCEC
destroying: 008DFCF8
```

When using MSVC (Visual Studio), the output is as expected. But GCC (4.8.2-19ubuntu1) outputs the following that shows that the destructors for the function parameters are being called after the first cout statement in main() but before the last one.

```
default constructor: 0x7fff2fcea510
other constructor: 0x7fff2fcea520
copy constructor: 0x7fff2fcea550
in member add
copy constructor: 0x7fff2fcea540
copy constructor: 0x7fff2fcea530
in function add
3 == 3
destroying: 0x7fff2fcea530
destroying: 0x7fff2fcea540
destroying: 0x7fff2fcea550
end of main
destroying: 0x7fff2fcea520
destroying: 0x7fff2fcea510
```

For those that are curious what clang++ (3.4-1ubuntu3) outputs.

```
default constructor: 0x7fff52cf9878
other constructor: 0x7fff52cf9870
copy constructor: 0x7fff52cf9860
copy constructor: 0x7fff52cf9858
in function add
3 == copy constructor: 0x7fff52cf9850
in member add
3
destroying: 0x7fff52cf9850
destroying: 0x7fff52cf9858
destroying: 0x7fff52cf9860
end of main
destroying: 0x7fff52cf9870
destroying: 0x7fff52cf9878
```

---

**Questions:**

1. My initial suspicion is that GCC is inlining the functions? If this is true is there a way to disable this optimization?
2. What section in the C++ spec would allow the destructors to be called after the cout in main? Especially of interest are the rules on inlining, if relevant, and when destructors are scheduled.

---

```
// Test.h
#ifndef __TEST_H__

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    int val;

    Test(Test const &a) : val(a.val)
    {
        cout << "copy constructor: " << this << endl;
    }

    Test() : val(1)
    {
        cout << "default constructor: " << this << endl;
    }

    Test(int val) : val(val)
    {
        cout << "other constructor: " << this << endl;
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        cout << "destroying: " << this << endl;
    }

    int add(Test b);
};

#endif
```

---

```
// Add.cpp
#include "Test.h"

int Test::add(Test b)
{
    cout << "in member add" << endl;
    return val + b.val;
}

int add(Test a, Test b)
{
    cout << "in function add" << endl;
    return a.val + b.val;
}
```

---

```
// Main.cpp
#include "Test.h"

int add(Test a, Test b);

int main()
{
    Test one, two(2);

    cout << add(one, two) << " == " << one.add(two) << endl;

    cout << "end of main" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

Compiled for GCC using:

```
g++ -c Add.cpp -o Add.o ; g++ -c Main.cpp -o Main.o ; g++ Add.o Main.o -o test
```

Comment: GCC simply optimises the calls to `add` by replacing them with `3` during compilation. Try compiling `add` in a separate unit and linking the two.

Comment: Now, do you know why you only see two constructors in your output, and 5 destructors? Can you tell which objects coorespond to each line in the output?

Comment: I split the code into several files, but still get the same results with GCC. I also don't understand why there are 2 constructors but 5 destructors. At least GCC and MVSC are consistent on this.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify "shows that the destructors are being called way after the objects have gone out of scope". What makes you think this? Which objects do you believe have gone out of scope and where?

Comment: There are more logs for destructors than constructors as the compiler generated copy constructor has no logging.

Comment: Don't write code like this in the first place. Your add() method should take both its arguments as `const` references.

Comment: Do add copy constructors, like: "Test(Test const &a) { val=a.val;}" This is were the extra 3 objects is coming from. Note though that adding these can change your results - a bit of a heisenberg effect. Also, as EJP suggests, experiment which changing the parameters of add to "Test const &". This will help you determine where the extra variables are coming from. Oh, and  add a print as the first statement in each Add() function - so you can see if the copy-ctors happen before or after the add functions.

Comment: Another thing missing in the test is a 2nd print before the return -- so we can see that the parameters are destroyed before the end of the function. Presumably, they are destroyed at the end of the "cout" full expression. The CLang output shows that the compiler is allowed to evaluate the subexpression in a different order. Other languages, like C#, more strictly specify the order in which sub expressions are evaluated. Presumably that would get in the way of some optimizations in some cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the C++ standard might be a little ambiguous regarding exactly when function parameter destructors must be called.  C++03 and C++11 both say in 5.2.2/4 "Function call" (emphasis added):

> The lifetime of a parameter ends when the function in which it is
>   defined returns.  The initialization and destruction of each parameter
>   occurs within the context of the **calling** function.

So the destructor for parameters doesn't occur conceptually at the function's closing brace. This is something I didn't know.

The standard gives a note explaining how this means that if the destructor for a parameter throws, then only exception handlers for the calling function or 'higher' are considered (specifically, even if the called function has a 'function-try-block', it is not considered).

While I think that the intent is for the MSVC behavior, I could see how someone might interpret a reading that allows the GCC behavior.

Then again, maybe it's a bug in GCC?

Comment: I was thinking e.g about `string::c_str()` where the `string` is temporary. GCC seems to be taking the *safer* way, not to destroy the `string` too early.

Comment: @firda: that's a temporary that is constructed (there's no parameter constructed for the call to the `c_str()` member function). C++ guarantees that temporaries will live until the end of the complete expression they're in. GCC seems to be doing this for parameters it constructs to call functions, which is different, but maybe it's allowed by the above phrasing.

Comment: To make myself clear, imagine: `cout << string("hello").c_str()`. But I think we understand each other. I was surprised that VC calls the destructor that early to write "3 == 3" that late.

Comment: @MichaelBurr so what section in the c++ spec allows a compiler to schedule "side-effects" (construction/destruction) when it wants?

Comment: I do think that @firda is on to something, in that it seems like GCC is treating the lifetime of called function parameters similar to how the lifetime of temporaries is required to be handled. Personally, that's not how I would interpret 5.2.2/4, but I can see how one might. I wonder how clang handles this (I don't have it installed)? Not that a "compiler vote" should necessarily determine what's correct, but...

Answer (score 2):

You create temporary objects when calling "add(a,b)", and when calling the member add(b).
I think what you are seeing in the case of gcc is that the local variables in the add() functions (the parameters) are destroyed when those functions return.
The last two "done" lines are for the variables "one" and "two".

VC is different - but this isn't wrong, it just shows that the two compilers are optimizing the code in different ways.

Instead of just printing "done", try also printing the value "this". Print "this" in the constructor as well, then you can see how the constructors and destructor calls are paired.

Oops - I mixed that up a bit between VC and GCC. VC prints "done" three times first - presumably as the add() parameters are destroyed, while GCC does them all last, probably because it inlined the add functions.

Comment: Is there a way to stop GCC from inlining the calls? I tried -O0 but that didn't work. So when a function is inlined the destructors get called where the calling function would normally call destructors instead of at the end of the inlined function?

Comment: @Justin: Why do you need a specific pattern of destructor calling anyway?

Comment: @SiyuanRen I don't "need" a specific pattern, but a teacher is using the MSVC compiler, and it would be helpful to be able to recreate the same behaviour the teacher expects (while still using GCC).

Answer (score 2):

Consider this line:

```
cout << add(one, two) << " == " << one.add(two) << endl;
```

Written as:

```
cout << add(one, two);
cout << " == " << one.add(two) << endl;
```

Would that change the printout for GCC?

Or that way:

```
auto i = add(one, two);
cout << i << " == ";
auto j = one.add(two)
cout << j << endl;
```

I think that this is about **side-effects** (not about inlining).
VC seems to be scheduling side-effects (destruction of temporary objects) earlier, while GCC schedules it at end of statement - `;`

---

[Added quote:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime)

> ### Temporary object lifetime
>
> Temporary objects are created in various situations: binding a
>   reference to a prvalue, returning a prvalue from a function, cast to a
>   prvalue, throwing an exception, entering an exception handler, and in
>   some initializations. **In every case, all temporaries are destroyed *as
>   the last step* in evaluating the full-expression** that (lexically)
>   contains the point where they were created, and if multiple
>   temporaries were created, they are destroyed in the order opposite to
>   the order of creation. This is true even if that evaluation ends in
>   throwing an exception.

In my opinion, this speaks for GCC and against VC (especially about printing "3 == 3" after the destruction, that is strange for me).

Comment: Do you know what section in the c++ spec allows for variations in side-effect scheduling?

Comment: First, I am not completely sure the naming for this is *side-effects*, but there is a section talking about sequence-points (old style), sequence-order (sequenced-before, sequenced-after - new style) and unsequenced (side-effects, especially post increments): [Order of evaluation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order)